# How to get all the documents before a particular document in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am implementing a chat module. I have messages in each conversation and when a particular user opens the conversation, I want to edit all the messages sent by others as read.

The message document looks like this:

```json
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("593a2a8fd957d847ba45eb6b"), 
  "senderId" : ObjectId("590c53a85fba594a59fe3d0f"), 
  "clientMessageId" : "02598F68-39BD-407A-ADDF-717148CB071C", 
  "conversationId" : ObjectId("592e7fab801be524e0df2591"), 
  "messageType" : "text", 
  "message" : "Yo", 
  "created" : NumberInt(1496984208), 
  "isRead" : false, 
  "isDelivered" : false, 
  "isDeleted" : false, 
  "isEdited" : false
}
```

The mongo code is as below:

```js
let filter = {
    conversationId: ObjectId(conversationId), //To get the conversation
    senderId: {
        $ne: ObjectId(userId) //All the messages sent by others 
    },
    isRead: false, //unread
    _id: {
        $lte: ObjectId(lastMessageId) //All the messages before the given messageid
    }
};

let update = {
    $set: {
        isRead: true,
        readTime: createdTime
    }
};

connection.collection("messagesv2").updateMany(filter, update, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    console.log(result)
```

This is not working. Can anyone point out why or how to go about implementing the same ?

Comment: what is `created` field in your document?

Comment: you cant compare with mongoDB Id wo get the documents before a particular document, as _id is created based on machineId,timestamp and other such factors. you may not get the documents created before that timestamp

Comment: Hey created is the time when it gets created.

Comment: then why dont you use that field to get the docs created before that document? In this case comparison will work fine

Comment: Do you have the created field of the doc with which you are comparing?

Comment: All the messages related to every conversation is in the message collection. I have to add these filters to get the messages of a particular conversation only. Also I found the solution, I had to add a check before. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I am comparing using messgeId to make it in sync with the UI.